# Continuity of integral

Tags: integral-transforms

Assume that $f:[0,2\pi]\to [0,2\pi]$ is a continuous function such that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ and define the function $$g(s)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin f(t+s)-\sin f(s)}{\sin t/2} dt.$$ Is $g$ continuous or bounded? Probably not. It is related to Marcel
Riesz's famous theorem.

Comment: So: $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, it is not true. Take $ f(x)=-1/\log x $ for $ 0 < x < 1/2 $, then extend to an odd function
on $ (-1/2,1/2) $, set $f(0)=0$ and extend to the whole interval continuously. Then $g(0)=+\infty$,
so $g$ can be neither continuous nor bounded.